# Hanuman found Sita in his second time visit to Lanka ( based on ChatGPT)?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman

I asked ChatGPT "Why Rama believed Hanuman that he only can locate Sita as per Valmiki Ramayana"?

[image]

but it has given me 3rd point as per the image where it mentioned Hanuman visited first time and collected some info about Sita and then second time he went to Lanka then he found Sita. Is that 3rd statement correct?

Comment: Firstly, I don't think times are so bad that we have to learn Ramayana from ChatGPT. Secondly, I assume #3 refers to Hanuman's knowledge of Lanka in Yuddha Kanda, previous to which he had explored the place (during the search for Sita in Sundara Kanda), which ChatGPT has wrongly imposed chronologically earlier.

Comment: Questions only need some background which can be anything - including "I remember reading .....".  ONly answers need scriptural backing.

Comment: ya, users have freedom to post any rando question. users also have freedom to vote to close such questions. ChatGPT is known to hallucinate (fancy term for lie).

Comment: Yep. Sadly, people would be more likely to answer this if the user said they heard it from their auntie or something. LLM false positives is something we'll have to deal with from now 'til forever. So, just voting to close a questions simply because it was inspired by machine learning is silly & futile. Just treat it like you would any other question—if you are able to get past your biases.